# ParameterEncoder Problem Updating Alamofire from version 4 to 5

Tags: swift, alamofire

I am updating my project from Alamofire version 4 to 5. And I am running into a snag. I use to encode my parameters with the follow :

```
// This struct lets us keep the square brackets in the HTTP GET Request vars to keep the php arrays in tact for the backend
struct BracketGetEncoding: ParameterEncoding {
    func encode(_ urlRequest: URLRequestConvertible, with parameters: Parameters?) throws -> URLRequest {
        var request = try URLEncoding().encode(urlRequest, with: parameters)
        request.url = URL(string: request.url!.absoluteString.replacingOccurrences(of: "%5B", with: "[").replacingOccurrences(of: "%5D", with: "]"))
        return request
    }
}

let request = AF.request(urlString, method: method, parameters: parameters, encoder: BracketGetEncoding(), headers: getRequestHeadersAsHTTPHeaders(), interceptor: nil, requestModifier: nil)
```

But I am trying to find the equivilant with the update. It now takes a ParameterEncoder instead of a ParameterEncoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two top level `request` methods: one that takes the new `ParameterEncoder` type, and one that takes the older `ParameterEncoding` type. You can use the old one by changing your `encoder` parameter to `encoding`.

I suggest you transition to the `ParameterEncoder` version when you can, as we're not sure if `ParameterEncoding` will be supported in the next major version of Alamofire.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the update for people who are looking to do the same thing :

```
// This struct lets us keep the square brackets in the HTTP GET Request vars to keep the php arrays in tact for the backend
struct BracketParameterEncoder : ParameterEncoder {
    func encode<Parameters>(_ parameters: Parameters?, into urlRequest: URLRequest) throws -> URLRequest where Parameters : Encodable {
        var request = try URLEncodedFormParameterEncoder.default.encode(parameters, into: urlRequest)
        request.url = URL(string: request.url!.absoluteString.replacingOccurrences(of: "%5B", with: "[").replacingOccurrences(of: "%5D", with: "]"))
        return request
    }
}
```